# Google search snippet add random words

Tags: html, wordpress, ads, search-engine, google-search

I created site using wordpress with some plugins :

[plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBEO3.png)

When I search for this site in Google, I can find a result with OK title and snippet (I think that's how is named this short text from site below title). But at the beginning of snippet, or on the end of it (in second result) there are added words like "swiss casino" or "super tiger". This words doesn't exists anywhere in code. So the results in google looks like :

```
Some Title
swiss casino This is some text from my site...
```

I have no idea what to do about it, I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Can you provide the URL?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably injected via Javascript or even only when an Agent named "google" or "bot" comes along.

It is a VERY clear indication that your website is hacked and compromised. As the code is probably sideloaded or encoded even a search through your code will probably not reveal the exact location.

It might be an old Wordpress version or an old plugin that was used as an entry point.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do you think that the solution may be "recreating" whole site as a new project but with updated versions of all components ?